# SQL best way to get an entry for every month from a start and end date

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a large table with a start_dt and an end_dt for each row and I want to add a row for every year and month that the row is present. So if the record was from March to June 2019, I would like to have 4 rows, one for each month it was in. What is the best way to this? Thanks

So from this
[image]

to this
[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Teradata has proprietary syntax for creating time series:

```
SELECT mytab.*, pd
  - extract the begin of the period and split it in YEAR/MONTH 
  ,To_Char(Begin(pd), 'MONTH')
  ,Extract(YEAR From Begin(pd))
FROM mytab
EXPAND ON PERIOD(start_dt, Last_Day(end_dt)) AS pd -- must be LAST_DAY to include the end month
       BY ANCHOR PERIOD Month_Begin -- one row for each month
```

Comment: Is there a way to limit it to only expand to the current date do you know?

Comment: @AndrewRowlands: What do you mean by *only expand to the current date*?

Comment: As in if the to_date is a long way in the future it will thousands of rows for each record when I really just want to see who has been active each month up to now? Thanks

Comment: You can simply define the min/max period adding e.g. `FOR PERIOD (DATE '2010-01-01', Current_Date)` after `BY ANCHOR PERIOD Month_Begin`. If your TD version supports LEAST on dates you can also use `EXPAND ON PERIOD(start_dt, Last_Day(least(end_dt, current_date))) AS pd` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use the calendar view for this.  Here's a simple example:

```
select
distinct f.id,
c.month_of_year,
c.year_of_calendar
from
vt_foo f
inner join sys_calendar.calendar c
    on c.calendar_date between f.start_dt and f.end_dt
order by id,month_of_year
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how performant an inner join is versus the build in expand on method mentioned above? Does it do a similar thing, or is it more effiecient? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with the month names as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
T.ID AS REC_ID
,TO_CHAR(C.CALENDAR_DATE, 'Month') AS MONTH_PRESE
,C.YEAR_OF_CALENDAR AS YEAR_PRESE
FROM
<target_tablename> AS F
INNER JOIN SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR AS C
    ON C.CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN F.START_DATE AND F.END_DATE
ORDER BY ID, MONTH_OF_YEAR;
```